# Stop Activity Function to allow deployment

Tags: azure, azure-durable-functions

I am looking into durable functions and one thing I am finding very scary is that there doesnt seem to be a way to stop an activity function

If this is truly the case how can deployment situations be covered where we might want to "start from scratch" and we are going to be updating the code

Unless I am misunderstanding something it appears as though in a deployment situation we could be held at the mercy of Activity functions, i.e. we can only deploy if there are no activity functions running?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

In Durable Functions, once an activity function is started, there is no built-in mechanism to forcefully stop it.

In deployment situations, where you need to update the code of an orchestration or activity function, there are strategies you can use

1. **Versioning**: You may look into versioning your Durable Functions. When deploying a new version, create a new version of your orchestration and activity functions. This allows you to run the new code for new instances while still allowing the existing instances to complete using the old code. You can control this using proxies and slot combination.
2. **Manual Intervention**: If you really need to forcefully stop activity functions, you might need to implement a custom mechanism. This could involve setting a flag in your orchestration data/a db that instructs activity functions to terminate early.Like a cancellation flag stored in DB. However, this can be complex and may not guarantee immediate termination.

Below is an example implementation. Please note that this is a basic illustration and may require further refinement for production use.

1. We will create a class to represent your document in Cosmos DB. This class should include a flag to signal termination:

```cs
public class WorkflowStatus
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldTerminate { get; set; }
}
```

2. In your orchestrator function, we can periodically check the Cosmos DB document to determine if termination is requested:

```cs
[FunctionName("OrchestratorFunction")]
public static async Task<string> RunOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Check the Cosmos DB document for the termination flag
        var workflowStatus = await context.CallActivityAsync<WorkflowStatus>("CheckTerminationFlag", null);

        if (workflowStatus.ShouldTerminate)
        {
            // Terminate the orchestration early
            return "Terminated";
        }

        // Your orchestration logic here

        // Optionally, add a delay between checks
        await context.CreateTimer(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5), CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

3. Create an activity function to check the termination flag in Cosmos DB:

```cs
[FunctionName("CheckTerminationFlag")]
public static WorkflowStatus CheckTerminationFlag(
    [ActivityTrigger] DurableActivityContext context)
{
    // Retrieve the document from Cosmos DB
    // Check the flag and return the WorkflowStatus object
    // Be sure to handle exceptions and errors appropriately
}
```

4. Implement a separate process or tool that can update the Cosmos DB document to set the `ShouldTerminate` flag when manual intervention is required.

This is a simplified example, and in a real-world scenario, you would need to handle errors, retries.

Comment: Ok so you mean call the checking activity function in my activity function? How would versioning work? Is that by the function name?

Comment: Versioning gets complicated, especially when you are using durable entities. We faced similar challenge, solved by keeping 2 different function apps to deploy using blue/green. Then we placed them behind our API Management for HTTP Triggers to invoke the right version. For Non HTTP Triggers, we had to make similar changes accordingly. We could have tried using Slots of Azure Functions, but we did not try that. You may want to explore slots for Blue/green pattern as well.

Comment: Ok thanks is there a specific place you could recommend for the blue green pattern? This seems like a huge restriction to me and it’s really making me hesitant about whether Durable functions are the way forward for me. I am just looking for an architecture I can use with premium functions that allow long running operations

Comment: More I think about it, The problem you are having is going to be a problem for any system which is having in-flight work. To ensure consistency, you will have to have some mechanics which allow you to request cancellation  of in-flight work. Durable functions currently do not propagate instance termination to activity or sub orchestrations. So they run to completion. Think about it like if you ask someone to go to london from new york, and he is in the flight, he will reach london, even if you abort that project.

Comment: With respect to your issue of deploying a new version, You can deploy a new version in a deplpyment slot or a different function app resource, and once you are sure that all in flight work is completed, Swap the Slot or Update your gateway/load balancer/proxy whichever mechanism you are using to implement the Blue / Green Pattern.

Comment: This should help you with Blue Green Deployment of Azure Durable Functions https://medium.com/@brentonlawson/azure-durable-functions-blue-green-deployment-701af5cdebaa